# Where generate HTML dynamically on browser or on server? [Mobile Web Development]

Tags: performance, web-applications, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a mobile web and sometimes I show a very large listview (I'm using JQM).

I notice that it takes several seconds to generate the big DOM from returned JSON in Javascript.

Do you think that is better to generate the HTML on the server and download from it compressed than iterate with Javascript through a JSON array?

**Edit:**

Finally I download all the data requested in one time, JSON compressed is not too heavy. Then I do a pagination rebuilding the listview with the corresponding data chunk, I'm rebuilding a 25 list items by page but the app is not so responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A best practice approach would be to use pagination and not send the whole JSON string from the server but split it in several "pages".

Something of the kind `infinite scroll` comes to mind for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on JS you're using to generate HTML. You should use innerHTML and arrays for string concatenation. You can also try pagination but it maybe tricky with JQM. Also, JQM is generally slow.

Answer (score 0):

How much data are you sending back and how many DOM nodes are you inserting?

What's the size difference between the JSON you're sending and the HTML that you would be sending instead?

I'd test both of the approaches for size and responsiveness and then make a choice.

One of the challenges you've got it responsiveness of the application vs radio use (longer radio use may be better for battery life than chatty connections with many sleep/wake/sleep cycles)

So I'd also look at how much data it makes sense to send in one go i.e. how much of it will be visible and used?